# Can literals in an SQL be substituted and result in same outcome for a SQL EXPLAIN plan in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

Imagine I have some arbitrary SQL which I wish to do an explain plan on for PostgreSQL.

```
select * from blah where s = 'value' and n = 1234
```

Would I get the same result from the explain plan if I were to substitute any literal values in the original SQL with a place holder value.

```
select * from blah where s = '?' and n = 0
```

My understanding of plain 'EXPLAIN' in PostgreSQL is that it does not execute the query and thus any explain plan is based on examining the structure of the query and seeing how that maps to tables, indexes etc.

So in large I expect that the values of literals would be immaterial, except maybe except for some corner cases such as empty strings vs non empty strings. Plus maybe in relation to certain types of index types perhaps. Not knowledgeable enough on this point about SQL databases to know though.

Is this assumption correct or does PostgreSQL take into consideration the value of literals appearing in the SQL when calculating the explain plan when using plain 'EXPLAIN' and not other types of explain plans such as 'EXPLAIN ANALYZE'?

Although I only give an example for 'SELECT', how might the same question apply when running explain plans on 'INSERT', 'UPDATE' and 'DELETE'?

Comment: As you mention about certain types of indexes, [partial indexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/static/indexes-partial.html) may be an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The literal values in the `SELECT` can affect the plan in at least two ways.

1) Optimizations may be performed given that constants are involved. For example the following are very different (granted they are degenerate cases):

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM blah WHERE 3=3;
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM blah WHERE 2=3;
```

2) Statistical data on the columns involved can allow the planner to make smarter choices in some circumstances. For example, I have a table with a large number of 1 record but very few (if any) numbers ~= 10000. The `EXPLAIN` results below demonstrate that the planner is using that information.

```
EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM blah WHERE number=1; 
                                         QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=25096.32..25096.33 rows=1 width=0)
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on blah (cost=1459.14..24983.15 rows=45268 width=0)
     Recheck Cond: (number = 1)
     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on blah_number_idx  (cost=0.00..1447.82 rows=45268 width=0)
               Index Cond: (number = 1)

EXPLAIN SELECT count(*) FROM blah WHERE number=12345;
                                              QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Aggregate  (cost=112.62..112.63 rows=1 width=0)
 ->  Index Only Scan using blah_number_idx on blah (cost=0.00..112.49 rows=52 width=0)
       Index Cond: (number = 13423)
```

If you believe the statistical data collected about columns is out of date, or if you adjust the amount to of detail to be saved, you can recompute these values using the `ANALYZE table;` command.

Comment: I am specifically wanting to know situations where they might just for plain EXPLAIN and not where ANALYSE is used. Are your comments restricted to only the ANALYSE case?